# Get touch input for touchscreen devices like androidPhone in unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-engine, unity3d-editor

I'm trying to make a game using unity and at this point I have created a cube object, a ground object a couple other things.  I can make it move by giving it a forward force.  I'm basically trying to make a game about a cube that you can navigate through obstacles.

What I want to know is how to get the input like touch input.  For example you would use `getkey("d")` If you wanted to get input from "d" in the keyboard.  How would I do the same except for touch input in android?

Comment: this isnt an android question. you should use the unity forums for this

Comment: Oh sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)
```

**Example**

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
    circle.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
}
```

Comment: Wow guys that was fast thanks for the help will try it as soon as possible

Comment: Your welcome if it was the answer of your question pleases accept the answer.thank you to.

Comment: How would i determine if the player is touching on the left side or right side of the screen

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html

You can use this to get a touch object which will give you the screen position, then you can use your cameras position and angle to cast a ray from that point to see if the user is touching the cube.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Im also wondering how i would determinche which side of the screen the player touched,sothat i can code the cube to move in that direction.

Comment: @user9262680 You get the touch coordinates in the touch object returned, compare those with your screen resolution so if it's so much x or y relative to your screen you call it a left  right up or down touch and call the appropriate method. I would do what I suggested in the answer though so the users taps compared to the cubes real position. just instead of testing if it touched the cube get the coordinates of where the ray intersects your floor.